# Concerns about modifying Node prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, nodelist

So, for fun, I decided to see if I could mimic the syntax/functionality of jQuery. This turned out to be fairly easy (when not worrying about cross-browser/legacy compatibility). You can see what I've done so far here: http://jsfiddle.net/FPAaM/3/

Now, in the interest of not stepping on the toes of other third-party javascript libraries, what concerns should be noted when adding functionality to the prototypes of `Node` and `NodeList`?

```
Node.prototype.text = function(txt){
    var chld = this.childNodes;
    while(chld[0]) this.removeChild(chld[0]);

    this.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txt));

    return this;
};
NodeList.prototype.text = function(txt){
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        this[i].text(txt);

    return this;
};
Node.prototype.css = function(tag, val){
    if (val != undefined)
        this.style[tag] = val;
    else
        return this.style[tag];

    return this;
};
NodeList.prototype.css = function(tag, val){
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        this[i].css(tag, val);

    return this;
};
Node.prototype.clk = function(cbk){
    this.addEventListener("click", cbk, false);

    return this;
};
NodeList.prototype.clk = function(cbk){
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        this[i].clk(cbk);

    return this;
};

var $ = function(args){
    if (typeof args == "function")
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", args, false);

    if (typeof args == "string")
        return document.querySelectorAll(args);

    return args;
};

$(function(){
    $("div.fancy").text("Poor man's jQuery!")
        .css("color", "red")
        .clk(function(e){
            if (this.css("color") == "red")
                $(this).css("color", "green");
            else
                this.css("color", "red");
        });
});
```

Comment: Ideally don't extend the prototype of any native objects. jQuery doesn't.

Comment: Because other libraries can do that as well and in ways you might not expect and which conflict with your code. Of course, many libraries disagree with this philosophy, [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/) being the obvious example.

Comment: There are two main reasons for not doing this: `Node` and `NodeList` are host objects; but this can be worked around after some testing. The main reason is that IE8 will puke at you when you will do this. If you don't support IE8, please go this way by all means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Node` and `NodeList` are ***host objects***. You should not extend them. The better way is to use a wrapper (like jQuery).

Check this: *[What's wrong with extending the DOM](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/)*